# QGIS Apply Correction to Elevation Datum

Tags: qgis, dem, raster-calculator, elevation, bathymetry

I am wanting to apply a blanket correction to a bathymetry layer i.e. add 2m to every DEM cell. I assume I do this in the Raster Calculator but I'm unsure of the command line to use.

Comment: And here also the question: "What have you tried?" - Did you have a look at the official tutorial e.g.?

Answer (score 5):

Use this expression in the raster calculator: `"name_of_your_dtm@1" + 2`

But as Erik suggested it you shall have a look at the official tutorial where most of the solutions are already provided :)

https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html